# MVVMCross Upgrade to Mono 3.2.3 has System.Net and System.Windows build erros

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am attempting to upgrade a Xamarin MVVMCross Mobile app from Mono 2.10.11 to 3.2.3. I have removed all of the build errors except for these two,

```
./M2 v2 (3.11)/M2.Core/BackendServices/MainAuthenticationService.cs(23,23): Error CS1070: 
The type `System.Net.CookieContainer' has been forwarded to an assembly that is not referenced. 
Consider adding a reference to assembly `System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' (CS1070) (M2.Core)
```

The other is : -

```
./M2 v2 (3.2.3)/M2.Core/ViewModels/AppointmentDataViewModel.cs(16,16): Error CS1070: 
The type `System.Windows.Input.ICommand' has been forwarded to an assembly that is not referenced. 
Consider adding a reference to assembly `System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' (CS1070) (M2.Core)
```

I have added System.Net and System.Windows into the references for the Core project. I have used different versions trying to get this to work including the GitHub binaries.

I have viewed each of the assemblies I have used to make sure the classes are contained within them but no luck.

I am not sure what I am missing. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is different depending on whether you are using Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS - and will change again as Xamarin continue to gradually release their latest PCL support.

Currently (on Xamarin stable channels today), :

- any PCL library should link to the standard reference assemblies
- for Xamarin.iOS UI projects, there are Mono/Xamarin assemblies for System.Windows and System.Net which you can link to (these are in the standard platform assemblies list)
- for Xamarin.Android UI projects, MvvmCross provides assemblies for System.Windows and System.Net within our nuget packages and within our binaries

For examples, takes a look at any of the example .csproj project files in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/ - all have been built on Mvx 3.0.13 and on Xamarin stable.

Comment: Sorry, Should have stated it is happening in Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Okay. From your answer I just took it that it was possible. I scrubbed the computer and rebuilt from the ground up. It now works. Still not sure what prevented it from picking it up in the first place. Thanks!